# Deriving the expression for work done by an ideal gas during expansion, $W = -P_{ext}\cdot\Delta V$, using dot product?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work, ideal-gas, volume

I was studying high school-level thermodynamics in chemistry and we were deriving the pressure-volume work done by an ideal gas confined by a frictionless piston. My textbook derived it in this way.

Consider a gas in a cylinder fitted with a frictionless piston. The pressure of the gas $P$ exerts a force on the piston, and it is balanced by equal and opposite pressure  $P_{ext}$ from outside the piston. If the area of the piston is $A$, then the force is $$F = P_{ext}\cdot A$$ If the piston moved by a distance $l$, the work done is $$W = F\cdot l$$ $$\implies W = P_{ext}\cdot A \cdot l$$ $$\implies W = P_{ext}\cdot\Delta V$$
And since work is done by the system in this case, work done will have a negative sign. $$\therefore W = -P_{ext}\cdot\Delta V$$ Now I want to ask if we can derive the same expression this way:-

Since the force $F$ is exerted by external pressure, it acts vertically downwards on the piston. During expansion, the piston moves up by a distance $l$. So the angle $\theta$ between the vectors $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{l}$ is $180^{\circ}$. So, the work done is $$W = \vec{F} \cdot \vec{l}$$ $$\implies W = F\cdot l \cdot cos(180^{\circ})$$ $$\implies W = -P_{ext}\cdot A \cdot l$$ $$\implies W = -P_{ext}\cdot\Delta V$$

Can anyone tell me if this is correct or if there is something that I am missing?

Also, since I was studying this in chemistry, the sign convention is different. I asked here because I wanted to know if there is a way to solve this by analyzing the direction of the force on the piston and the displacement of the piston. Thanks in advance!

Comment: work done *on the system* is -p(ext).v

Comment: @PrateekMourya I am sorry, I should have mentioned that this was my chemistry textbook. I asked on the Physics SE cause I used the definition of work, i.e., the dot product. I will edit the question to reflect the the difference in sign convention.

Comment: The work done by the system on the surroundings is $P\Delta V=P_{ext}\Delta V$.  The work done by the surroundings on the system is $-P_{ext}\Delta V=-P\Delta V$.  I. think your derivation is more understandable than that given by your textbook.

Comment: @ChetMiller Okay, thank you! So in case, I wish to use the same equations in chem, I will just reverse the signs I guess. Because of the difference in sign conventions.

Comment: If you mean that, in chem, you use the work done by the surroundings on the gas, then yes.